# Getting differences between collections in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of image paths, and a larger collection of Image objects (Which contain a path property). I have the code to check for any matching images, but if there are supposed to be four matching image paths (as that is how many are in the first collection), and there is less than this, how can I get the missing one without writing loops?

```
        List<string> ImagesToCheck = new List<string>()
        {
            "",
            "s",
            "ssdd"
        };

        IEnumerable<HtmlImage> Images = manager.ActiveBrowser.Find.AllControls<HtmlImage>();

        var v = from i in Images
                where ImagesToCheck.Any(x => x == i.Src)
                select i;

        if (v.Count() < 3)
        {

        }
```

So I need to get the items which are *not* in the collection titled v, but are in ImagesToCheck.

How could I do this with LINQ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for any paths in ImagesToCheck that have not been used in the Images collects as a .Src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
var images = from s in ImagesToCheck where !i.Any(c => c.Path == s) select s;
```

Something along those lines..

Ian

Answer (score 0):

ImagesToCheck.Where(x => !v.Contains(x))

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = ImagesToCheck.Where(i => !v.Contains(i));
```

Comment: `var results = ImagesToCheck.Where(i => !v.Contains( thisImage => thisImage.Path == i));` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = from s in ImagesToCheck where i.All(c => c.Path != s) select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this answer was posted, but Linq has Intersect and [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx). The last one will give you all the items from the first collection, except those that are also in the second collection.
Disadvantage is that `Except` uses the standard `Equals()` operator or an `IEqualityComparer<T>` and you are matching on the Path property. But eventually you will be able to write something like:

```
ImagesToCheck.Except(Images)
```

Which I think is pretty neat.